# How to hold the life cycle of component after constructor till the function in constructor was not completed?

Tags: angular

I am working on angular2 application.

I have a component which will display my menu. In this component I have a list of menu items (array) and in constructor I am calling an api to get permissions of menu items in true/false. In HTML file looping through menuList array to print it and compering every menuList item with permissions object. If there is permission then it will display it otherwise no.

I am getting an error because api takes time to return data but html was build before it returns response. That's why I want first to get response of api after that initialisation of component.

Comment: Could you provide some more context about what you're trying to do? It's possible a [resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data), which will block loading until the required data is available, might be what you're trying to describe.

Comment: i guess you are looking for `router resolve` as pointed out by @jonrsharpe

Comment: It's not clear what error you're getting, but there are other ways to deal with async data in components. From my blog, for example: http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html

Comment: hey, did [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45410694/2545680) help?

Answer (score 1):

> In HTML file looping through menuList array to print it
>   I'm assuming you're using `ngFor` and construction like this to show the items:

```
<menu-item *ngFor="let item of menuItems"..>
```

The best approach in this case would be not fill `menuItems` with values until you get the response from the server. Something along these lines:

```
export class MenuComponent {
  menuItems = [];
  constructor(s: BackEndService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
       s.getPermissions().toPromise().then((permissions)=>{
          permissions.forEach(()=>{
             // some calculations
             menuItems.push(item);
          })
       })
  }
}
```